# How to remove this unnecessary high waveform that prevents me from amplifying to the highest possible (but still fine) decibel?

Tags: audacity, waveform, limiters

I want to remove all these [high waveform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqKDf.png) (there are about 8 in this 5 minutes track, which I bookmarked), because if I select all > effect > Amplify, It only amplify [about 3.2 db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwCHf.png), but if I exclude those high waveform, I'd be able to Amplify [about 5.6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4TuV.png), which is what I'm trying to achieve to the whole 5 minutes track.

Just a comparison of high waveform [excluded vs included](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOfZR.png).

I'm working on a 1 hour track that contains about a hundred of high waveform. I think removing them one by one is not a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to apply a brickwall limiter with a threshold around -6 dBFS to the track. That should lower the higher audio peaks. You would then have room to apply a higher gain to the whole track.

Be aware that a limiter might produce undesirable artifacts, you should therefore test the limiter settings on a few peaks to fine tune the threshold before processing the whole track.